# Android Room: Synchronous queries return null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a `Site` and corresponding `SiteDao`:

```
@Dao
interface SiteDao {
    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM site WHERE uid = 1 LIMIT 1")
    val site: LiveData<Site>

    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM site WHERE uid = 1 LIMIT 1")
    val getSiteSync: Site

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(context: Site)
}
```

This works:

```
siteRepository.getSite().observe(activity, Observer<Site> {
     // `it` is instance of Site, working as intended
})
```

This doesn't:

```
Thread {
    val site = siteRepository.getSiteSync()
    // site is null
}.start()
```

Nevermind that I'm using *Repository* instead of *ViewModel*, just an example.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Room doesnt allow synchronous queries by default.

To achieve that you have to explicity call [allowMainThreadQueries](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#allowMainThreadQueries()) while initializing your database.

That is designed that way because database selection should observe for changes and ain't fetched immediately.

Comment: I am having a problem understanding Room because not all data in a DB changes, I find it not simple to need to make an AsyncTask again each time I want to fetch the DB, I am kind of dissapointed this new component did not get so easy to use at the end.

Comment: @David They really want you to use LiveData or RxJava. Then it's super simple to just always have up to date Data in your views or whereever else you might need it. Requerying by hand should be avoided, if that's ever necessary, consider LiveData.