# Is it necessary to define the functions inside the DAO as suspend?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm creating a simple app using Room. I have created a DAO interface:

```
interface ItemDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    fun addItem(item: Item)
}
```

And a repository interface:

```
interface ItemRepository {
    fun addItem(item: Item)
}
```

Here is the implementation of the function:

```
class ItemRepositoryImpl(
    private val itemDao: ItemDao
) : ItemRepository {
    override fun addItem(item: Item) = itemDao.addItem(item)
}
```

And inside the ViewModel class I launch a coroutine using viewModelScope:

```
class ItemViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: ItemRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    fun addItem(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repo.addItem(item)
    }
}
```

When I call `addItem` from the UI, the item is successfully added to Room. Now the question is, is it mandatory to set the addItem function inside the ItemDao interface as a **suspend** function? If yes, why? I'm really confused.

**Edit**:

Here is how I create an instance of my db:

```
fun provideItemDb(
    @ApplicationContext
    context : Context
) = Room.databaseBuilder(
    context,
    ItemDb::class.java,
    "item_table"
).build()
```

Comment: Do you have `allowMainThreadQueries` on by chance? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47112210/833647

Comment: @KenWolf No, I don't. Please check my updated question. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you calling the DAO functions from a non-main thread? That’s permitted even if they aren’t defined to suspend.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm calling `repo.addItem(item)` in the ViewModel class from within a `viewModelScope`, and inside the repository implementation, I'm using `itemDao.addItem(item)`. So can you help me with answer please? I'm quite confused. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you show your code where you call it from a `viewModelScope`? It depends on what CoroutineContext you're using whether it's getting called on the main thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suspend functions are not required, but if you don't mark the functions as `suspend`, then they block, so they are not safe to call on the main thread.

If you are using coroutines, it is safe to call a blocking IO function, but only if your current CoroutineContext is not using `Dispatchers.Main`. You are currently getting away with not using `suspend` functions because you are running your coroutine with `Dispatchers.IO`, so the function is called off of the main thread.

If you are using coroutines, for code simplicity you should always mark them `suspend`, so the functions are easier and more versatile to use. Imagine if, for example, you wanted to also update a LiveData with the row ID of the newly added item. (You can do this by returning a Long in the DAO function.)

If you use `suspend` in your DAO, your function could be:

```
fun addItem(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch {
    _latestRowLiveData.value = repo.addItem(item)
}
```

If you didn't use `suspend` in your DAO, your function would have to be one of these more convoluted implementations:

```
fun addItem(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch {
    _latestRowLiveData.value = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { repo.addItem(item) }
}

// or

fun addItem(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    _latestRowLiveData.postValue(repo.addItem(item))
}

// or

fun addItem(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val rowId = repo.addItem(item)
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        _latestRowLiveData.value = rowId
    }
}
```

Now imagine a function that wants to do a series of various actions. The non-suspend version of your DAO would lead to very messy-looking (and therefore bug-prone) coroutines in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

> Now the question is, is it mandatory to set the addItem function inside the ItemDao interface as a suspend function?

*Mandatory*? No (you see that for yourself since it works).

*Recommended*? Yes.

> If yes, why? I'm really confused.

Do you want to have to remember to call `addItem` in a coroutine with the `IO` context *every single time* you call it? Or do you want it to just work correctly (run in a coroutine on the IO thread) regardless of where you call it from?

That's why you make it `suspend` *and* switch to the `IO` context within that call. Then It Just Works™.

Comment: "and switch to the IO context within that call" What do you mean by this? Room already uses a thread pool to do the work of suspend functions, and it's not the IO dispatcher. Suspend functions don't block--by convention, the caller *never* has to worry about what dispatcher is in the current CoroutineContext when calling a suspend function. If you had to use IO dispatcher every time you call a Room function, there would be no benefit to marking it `suspend`.

Comment: That was a general statement that the function marked `suspend` should switch to whatever context it needs if necessary so the outside caller doesn't have to worry about it. Indeed, this is what Room does for you, as you said, so my suggestion is applying that principle to the OP's own code. But just because Room does it, we should not generally assume "the caller _never_ has to worry...when calling a suspend function". That's a blanket statement that won't always be true.

Comment: The way your sentence is worded sounds like you *have* to specify IO context to make it work. "never has to worry" is true if conventions are followed, but yes, it's always possible you're calling buggy code. If a Google engineer checked in a change that made a suspend function block, it would absolutely be labeled a bug when discovered.

Comment: No, I was saying the OP would move their `withContext` call to within the suspend function to execute the same behavior as they had when it was outside the call. English is hard. And what I mean by "never have to worry" not being true is that you cannot assume a `suspend` function is running on any given dispatcher. Room will do it for you because it's a library dealing with IO so using the IO dispatcher automatically makes sense. But you would not expect a generic suspend function like `delay` to switch to a specific dispatcher. _That_ would be a bug.

Comment: But you *do* expect every suspend function to be CoroutineContext-agnostic. You never have to worry about what the current CoroutineContext is when calling a suspend function, because a suspend function (**if the programmer who designed it is following convention**) internally and temporarily, switches to any specific context that it needs. `delay` is a weird case because it suspends without any regard to any dispatchers. You won't find a single suspend function in any Google, Jetbrains, or Square/CashApp library whose documentation says something like "must not be called on Dispatchers.Main".

Comment: So yes, you can't assume a suspend function is running on any particular dispatcher, but also you shouldn't care. It's an internal encapsulated detail of the suspend function.

Comment: I disagree with `delay` being a "weird" case - IMO _most_ suspend functions should be written without switching context (instead inheriting the context of the calling code) unless there's a specific need (like a DB or Networking library wanting to ensure use of the IO dispatcher). We may be saying the same thing different ways. In any case, this is veering far off the reservation of the original question.

Comment: Indeed, we might.